# Triggering UITableView to show new rows when insert on chat application

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement a chat application. I would like to know how can I trigger second users UITableView to show new message when first user send a text. I'm using parse.com for backend service and UITableView to show messages.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding an NSTimer and calling update table method in it.